# Unable to echo dynamic data in facebook metatags

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I've successfully added facebook's social plugin to my news page (which itself dynamically creates all the article pages which appear under it). I've added metatags however cannot understand how to echo dynamic data within the metatags, especially since that data is generated later in the code. ie. My fb metatags are within the **head** of my **news.php**

```
<head>   ... *(other stuff)*
<meta property="og:title" content="When Great Minds Go To Sleep" />
</head>
```

However it doesn't make sense for me to statically provide this content since there are many news article pages that will be generated other than this. I want the content to be picked up from what is generated dynamically later in the file (after all this is one of many news pages). ie. I want to be able to say, `content="<?php echo $data[0]['title']; ?>"`. However the $data array is generated only later in **news.php,** at the start of the **body**:

```
<?php 
                if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {// user gets here by clicking on link with id
                    $id_raw = trim(htmlentities($_REQUEST["id"]));
                    $data = news_data_id($conn, $id_raw);
                    ?>          

                    <h2><?php echo $data[0]['title']; ?></h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo $data[0]['filepath'];?>" style="float: left; max-height: 5em; margin: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0; -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50%); shape-outside: circle(50%);">
                    <p><?php echo $data[0]['body']; ?></p>
```

So when I do try

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $data[0]['title']; ?>" />
```

nothing turns up except the default 'Title'.

How can this be addressed then? Would appreciate any guidance on this issue.

Comment: you would need to generate your `$data` array at the start of your page or before `head` tag so that before accessing the `$data` you have it defined.

Comment: @Sagar Guhe - there has to be a better way of doing it - this would totally disrupt the organised structure of the code

Comment: yes this would disrupt the structure and there are better ways to deal with this but also you may need to restructure your code, or you can simple use work arround which I would not recommend personally...

Comment: is there a way for the metatag getting / reading the id of the page generated dynamically using some $_variable or session variable

Comment: I don't think so  as PHP works top to down...

Comment: Then, is there a way i can acheive the equivalent of the metatags after $data is generated in the body? How do so many websites do this then - they can't be breaking their structure.

Comment: May be you can use jQuery/javascript for this but I don't know how successful it would to use it for the sake of its purpose