# How do sites put dynamic php content into facebook meta tags?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I've just added facebook meta tags to my **news.php** page. This file also dynamically generates article (urls) pages under it. But how am i to set the title for the fb meta tag in the head (ie. `<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $data[0]['title']; ?>" />`) when the $data is getting defined / populated lower down in the body? 
**How do so many sites do it?**
Would be grateful for any guidance on this.

Below is the code for my page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Title</title>

    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="6666666666666"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $data[0]['title']; ?>" />

         </head>

  <body>
  <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '66666666666666',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.5'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script> 

    <header>


<div class="contentwrap">
            <article>
                <h1>- News- </h1>
                <?php 
                if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {// user gets here by clicking on link with id
                    $id_raw = trim(htmlentities($_REQUEST["id"]));
                    $data = news_data_id($conn, $id_raw);
                    ?>          

                    <h2><?php echo $data[0]['title']; ?></h2>
                    <img src="<?php echo $data[0]['filepath'];?>" style="float: left; max-height: 5em; margin: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0; -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50%); shape-outside: circle(50%);">
                    <p><?php echo $data[0]['body']; ?></p>

    <div
  class="fb-like"
  data-share="true"
  data-width="450"
  data-show-faces="false">
</div>              


                <?php }
                else {  
(continues)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to echo dynamic data in facebook metatags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473703/unable-to-echo-dynamic-data-in-facebook-metatags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the best option to switch your website to `mvc` structure here is detailed article whot is `mvc pattern`: http://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/

For now without major changes you can change yoru `news.php` structure so that it will retrieve all content php data at the top before html part, so in that case you will have your `$news` variable at all places of your html and can easily create `mattes` and show content in `body`

Comment: thanks - i will go for the latter, but just wanted to know - in the pre-html part, will now check for id using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI]'` (not $_REQUEST['id']) - how can i extract id from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI]'` if the page url is `http://www.hensofwar.com/news?id=6`

Comment: you can use solution from answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784243/how-do-i-extract-query-parameters-from-a-url-string-in-php ,  but actually i did not got why you want to switch to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`? as you have access also to `$_REQUEST['id']` at the same place

Comment: because actually the above file news.php has been split into 2 files - so the head is in one and the body is in another, so if i copy the `if` of the body to before the html, i'm not sure i'll be getting the values (unless i use a session variable?)

Comment: So if in your case you have `head.php` and `body.php` anyway if you execute it under domain.com/news.php and include in `news.php` one by one `head.php` and `body.php` you will get anyway same `$_REQUEST` everywhere so you will have your $_REQUEST['id']

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use [Output buffering control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) in your whole site to handle this.

Basically `ob_start()` on the first life of your file and `ob_get_clean()` to retrieve everything outputted during the execution.